# "None of [Index(['latitude', 'longitude'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with geolocations and I am attempting to create a column and pass a function to it that would get walkscores for every location.

This is my dataframe:

```
df_test[['latitude', 'longitude']]

    latitude    longitude
0   50.673170   -120.322639
1   50.669597   -120.341833
2   50.650727   -120.150661
3   50.687545   -120.297688
4   50.772361   -122.811211
5   50.882304   -119.865000
6   50.643431   -120.362385
7   50.707459   -120.376297
8   50.708614   -120.409419
9   50.697850   -120.389101
10  50.659250   -119.998597
```

When I test the function on a single variable, everything works fine:

```
walkscore(df_test['latitude'][0], df_test['longitude'][0], key)

71
```

But when I tried to pass this function to the entire dataset, the following way, I got an error:

```
df_test.loc['walkscore'] = df_test.loc[['latitude', 'longitude']].\
    apply(lambda x:
                    walkscore(x['latitude'], x['longitude'], apikey), axis='columns')

KeyError: "None of [Index(['latitude', 'longitude'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

I tried resetting the index, but it's not helping. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `loc`, because need seelct columns, not index values:

```
df_test['walkscore'] = df_test.\
    apply(lambda x: walkscore(x['latitude'], x['longitude'], apikey), axis='columns')
```

Verify with sample function:

```
apikey = 'aaa'
def walkscore(x, y, apikey):
    return tuple((x, y))

df_test['walkscore'] = df_test.\
    apply(lambda x: walkscore(x['latitude'], x['longitude'], apikey), axis='columns')

print (df_test)
     latitude   longitude                                  walkscore
0   50.673170 -120.322639                    (50.67317, -120.322639)
1   50.669597 -120.341833  (50.669596999999996, -120.34183300000001)
2   50.650727 -120.150661           (50.650727, -120.15066100000001)
3   50.687545 -120.297688                   (50.687545, -120.297688)
4   50.772361 -122.811211           (50.772361, -122.81121100000001)
5   50.882304 -119.865000                      (50.882304, -119.865)
6   50.643431 -120.362385                   (50.643431, -120.362385)
7   50.707459 -120.376297                   (50.707459, -120.376297)
8   50.708614 -120.409419          (50.708614000000004, -120.409419)
9   50.697850 -120.389101                    (50.69785, -120.389101)
10  50.659250 -119.998597                    (50.65925, -119.998597)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @jezrael. When I run the function, it gives me a list of walk score values in the response line, however, when I look up the walkscore column, its all None values

Comment: @user4718221 - if use my sample function `def walkscore(x, y, apikey):
    return tuple((x, y))` it working ?

Comment: it is. I checked the API and its working fine, it just won't put the proper results in the dataframe somehow

Comment: @user4718221 - yes, I only want to test, if get same output like in my answer if use my custom `walkscore` function.

Comment: yes, your function seems to be working. Any clue what might be causing None results to appear in the dataframe?

Comment: @user4718221 - Not idea. Is possible share `walkscore` function ?

Comment: @user4718221 - there is key :( So I cannot test it :(

Comment: never mind, I fixed it. I had print(walkscore) instead of return so it wouldn't register anything to the dataframe. Thanks so much for your help!